# What are these weird symbols showing up in my source code listings?

Tags: listings

I have a LaTeX document, and am trying to embed some Java code via the listings package.  I have the following LaTeX source:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\title{Sample Document}
\begin{document}

\section*{Source Code:}

\lstset{ language=Java }
\lstinputlisting{example.java}

\end{document}
```

And, for the most part, the code shows up nicely.  But, in certain places I get these weird symbols where spaces should be (code coloring added):

[image: In certain places there are weird |_| symbols instead of spaces]

It appears that, within any quoted string, the spaces are converted to these U-like symbols. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) illustrating the problem?

Comment: Those are there to indicate that there is a space.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spaces in strings appear as the symbol you mentioned. To suppress the symbols showing the spaces, add the option `showstringspaces=false` to `\lstset`.